# Меню предыдущего фрагмента реагирует на нажатия

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть активити. При его запуске я добавляю в него фрагмент ArticleFragment, в нём есть меню и список RecyclerView. При нажатии на элемент списка, я добавляю такой же фрагмент в стек поверх старого. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку меню верхнего фрагмента, меню предыдущих фрагментов тоже реагируют на нажатия. Я пробовал всё что мог: добавлял android:clickable="true" в разметку фрагмента, и пробовал создавать кнопки меню динамически, и очищать меню. Единственное решение к которому я смог придти, это заменять фрагменты, а не добавлять: replace() вместо add(). Но это решение мне не подходит, ведь тогда при возврате статьи будут грузиться заново.
Код активити:

```
public class ArticleHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "title";
private static final String EXTRA_LINK = "link";
private static final String EXTRA_DATE = "date";

private String mArticleTitle, mArticleDate, mArticleLink;

private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private Fragment mArticleFragment;

public static Intent newInstance(Context context, String title, String link, String date){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ArticleHostActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LINK, link);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_base);

    mArticleTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
    mArticleDate = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATE);
    mArticleLink = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LINK);
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mArticleFragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance(mArticleDate, mArticleTitle, mArticleLink);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.article_fragment_host, mArticleFragment).commit();
  }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Article mArticle;
private ArrayList<ArticlePart> mArticleParts;
private ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
private AppCompatActivity mActionBar;
private Realm mRealm;

private static final int MENU_ADD = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_SHARE = Menu.FIRST + 1;

private String mArticleTitle, mArticleDate, mArticleLink;

private static final String ARG_ARTICLE_DATE = "article_date";
private static final String ARG_ARTICLE_TITLE = "article_title";
private static final String ARG_ARTICLE_LINK = "article_link";

private boolean mSaved;

public static ArticleFragment newInstance(String date, String title, String link){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_DATE, date);
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_TITLE, title);
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_LINK, link);
    ArticleFragment articleFragment = new ArticleFragment();
    articleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return articleFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mArticleTitle = (String) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_TITLE);
    mArticleDate = (String)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_DATE);
    mArticleLink = (String)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_LINK);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Realm.init(getContext());
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_fragment, container, false);
    mToolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_article);
    mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_article);
    mArticleParts = new ArrayList<>();
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.article_recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mArticle = new Article(mArticleDate, mArticleTitle, mArticleLink);
    mActionBar = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    mActionBar.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    if(mActionBar.getSupportActionBar() != null){
        mActionBar.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    mActionBar.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    if(mArticleDate != null){
        mActionBar.setTitle(mArticleDate);
    }else {
        mActionBar.setTitle("...");
    }

    if(!checkArticleInRealm(mArticleLink)){
        new FetchPartsTask(mArticleLink, this).execute();
    }
    mAdapter = new ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mArticleTitle, mArticleParts);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return v;
}

/*@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.article_menu, menu);
    if (mSaved){
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorited);
    }else {
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_not_favorited);
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    menu.add(0, MENU_ADD, Menu.NONE, R.string.to_favs_button_hint).setVisible(true);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SHARE, Menu.NONE, R.string.share_button_hint).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_share).setVisible(true);
    if (mSaved){
        menu.getItem(MENU_ADD).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorited);
    }else {
        menu.getItem(MENU_ADD).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_not_favorited);
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getOrder()){
        case MENU_SHARE:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.share_button_hint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MENU_ADD:
            if(!mSaved){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.added_to_favs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorited));
                addArticleToRealm();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.deleted_from_favs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_not_favorited));
                deleteArticleFromRealm();
            }
            mSaved = !mSaved;
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Разметка активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/article_fragment_host">
</FrameLayout>
```

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context="ru.xxx.xxx.xxx.ArticleHostActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_article"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_article"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_article_progressbar"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/article_recyclerview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressbar_article"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/show_comments_button"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:text="@string/show_comments_button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_recyclerview"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код добавления фрагмента при нажатии на элемент списка:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(pos == mFirstExtraLinkPosition){
            fragment = WebViewFragment.newInstance(part.getContentLink());
        }else {
            fragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance(null, part.getText(), part.getContentLink());
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.article_fragment_host, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

Может быть возможно как-нибудь динамически генерировать id у пунктов меню при создании фрагмента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге динамическая генерация оказалась вроде не нужна. Я убрал переопределение метода onOptionsItemSelected() и переопределил метод onCreateOptionsMenu() таким образом:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.article_menu, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            if(!mSaved){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.added_to_favs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorited));
                addArticleToRealm();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.deleted_from_favs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_not_favorited));
                deleteArticleFromRealm();
            }
            mSaved = !mSaved;
            return true;
        }
    });
    menu.getItem(1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.share_button_hint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Короче говоря, я на каждый элемент повесил свой слушатель нажатий. Вроде работает.
Я не учёл, что сказано в документации по меню:

> Если в вашей операции имеются фрагменты, система сначала вызовет метод onOptionsItemSelected() для операции, а затем будет вызывать этот метод для каждого фрагмента (в том порядке, в котором они были добавлены), пока он не возвратит значениеtrue или не закончатся фрагменты.